# weird exception occurs with negative numbers

Tags: vb.net, indexoutofboundsexception

here is my code:

```
        Dim index As Integer
 do
  index = find difference(board1,board2)
    if index = - 1 then 
      exit do
   end if
 loop
```

find difference is a function that returns an integer, I have set it to return -1 if no difference is found so then the loop exits, however this gives me an outofbounds exception. i have put a try statement around the line `index = find difference(board1,board2)` and it catches -1 as an exception with the message:

index was out of range.

must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

parameter name: index.

I am at a loss as to what can be causing this, any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

find_difference:

```
 dim indy as integer
 dim indexes as list(of integer)
 dim info as integer = 0
 indexes.add(-1)
 for each cell in cells
 if cell.info > info then
   indexes.clear
   indexes.add(cell.index)
 else if cell.info = info then
   indexes.add(cell.index)
 end if
 next 

 indy  = Math.Floor((indexes.Count + 1) * Rnd())
 return indexes(indy)
end function
```

Comment: could you please post the funcion `find difference`?

Comment: it involves a lot of my heavily involved program so I will abridge it as best I can

Answer (score 1):

There is only one statement in the `find_difference` function which uses an index:

```
return indexes(indy)
```

Which indicates the value of `indy` is computed as -1 or above the size of the collection:

```
indy  = Math.Floor((indexes.Count + 1) * Rnd())
```

If indexes.Count is 1 and [Rnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is greater than 0.5 then indy will be computed as 1 which would be outside the range of the collection. The `+ 1` should be removed.

Comment: thanks, that was definitely one issue I had, however when indexes(indy) = -1 I still get an exception that I can not explain.

Comment: @maxG795 - then the value of indy is still outside the range of the collection.  What is the value of indy when the exception occurs and what is the length of the collection.  If you add those values to your exception message, it should tell you what the problem is.